# Custom map of the area with a marker

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in java and android, so I would like to get a couple of tips on how to implement a map of a local area (map images are stored locally in png, jpg formats), with a static marker that can be set by coordinates relative to the upper-left corner of the map in pixels. The whole problem is that it is necessary to implement scrolling and zooming of the map with your fingers, and when implementing this idea, you cannot keep the marker static relative to the map.

```
MapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
                DebugText.setText(" ");
                int actionMask = event.getActionMasked();
                // индекс касания
                int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                // число касаний
                int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

                float curX, curY;
                float scle = MapView.getScaleX();
                MapView.getLocationInWindow(location);
                int mapX = (int) (location[0] / scle);
                int mapY = (int) (location[1] / scle);



                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        curIndexTouch = pointerIndex;
                        inTouch = true;
                        mx = event.getX();
                        my = event.getY();
                        mapX = MapView.getScrollX();
                        mapY = MapView.getScrollY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        curX = event.getX();
                        curY = event.getY();
                        MapView.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                        planeImageView.setY((int)(my - curY));
                        planeImageView.setX((int) (mx - curX));
                        mx = curX;
                        my = curY;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        inTouch = false;
                        curX = event.getX();
                        curY = event.getY();
                        mx = curX;
                        my = curY;
                        MapView.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                        planeImageView.setY((int)(my - curY));
                        planeImageView.setX((int) (mx - curX));
                        break;
                }
                ImageView view = (ImageView) arg0;
                view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);


                dumpEvent(event);
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                        mode = NONE;
                        Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                        oldDist = spacing(event);
                        Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                        if (oldDist > 5f) {
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(mid, event);
                            mode = ZOOM;
                            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        if (mode == DRAG)
                        {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                        }
                        else if (mode == ZOOM)
                        {
                            // pinch zooming
                            float newDist = spacing(event);
                            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                            if (newDist > 5f)
                            {
                                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                MAPscale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                // zoom out
                                matrix.postScale(MAPscale, MAPscale, mid.x, mid.y);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }

                view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen
                planeImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                MapView.getLocationInWindow(location);
```

I tried using scrollBy and SetY, but in both cases the plane marker lagged behind the map itself in movement